# TensorFlow 2.0 - Begineer Implementing simple CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I just finished DL specialization from Coursera and I am trying to implement a CNN with TensorFlow 2.0 and my own collected data. I followed the guide and documentation from tensorflow.org and was able to set up a pipeline to load my image. However, when I ran the model I kept running into **memory/resource-related issues**.

My model should do a multi-label classification with 30 categories. below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D

#Import helper modules
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib
import os
import pandas as pd
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

#Define path to directories
train_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'train'
validation_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'validation'
test_dir = pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'test'

#Read csv file containing filename and label
train_csv = pd.read_csv(pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'train.csv')
validation_csv = pd.read_csv(pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'validation.csv')

#Define total number of training and validation set
total_train = train_csv.shape[0]
total_val = validation_csv.shape[0]
print(f'Total training images: {total_train}')
print(f'Total validation images: {total_val}')
```

the below code is from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

```
CLASS_NAMES = np.array([item.name for item in train_dir.glob('*')])

#set up variables
BATCH_SIZE = 128
TRAIN_STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(total_train/BATCH_SIZE)
VAL_STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(total_val/BATCH_SIZE)
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

#using td.data.Dataset
train_list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(train_dir/'*/*'))
valid_list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(validation_dir/'*/*'))

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES


def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

def show_batch(image_batch, label_batch):
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
  for n in range(25):
      ax = plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
      plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
      plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[label_batch[n]==1][0].title())
      plt.axis('off')

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
train_labeled_ds = train_list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
valid_labeled_ds = valid_list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

def prepare_for_training(ds, cache=True, shuffle_buffer_size=1000):
  # use `.cache(filename)` to cache preprocessing work for datasets that don't
  # fit in memory.
  if cache:
    if isinstance(cache, str):
      ds = ds.cache(cache)
    else:
      ds = ds.cache()

  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)

  # Repeat forever
  ds = ds.repeat()

  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

  # `prefetch` lets the dataset fetch batches in the background while the model
  # is training.
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

  return ds

train_ds = prepare_for_training(train_labeled_ds)
x_train, y_train = next(iter(train_ds))
valid_ds = prepare_for_training(valid_labeled_ds)
```

the model is from the tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(30, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(train_ds.repeat(), 
          epochs=15, batch_size= BATCH_SIZE, 
          validation_data=valid_ds.repeat(), steps_per_epoch= TRAIN_STEPS_PER_EPOCH,        
          validation_steps=VAL_STEPS_PER_EPOCH)
```

at first I ran into **Input ran out of data**, so i changed my input dataset into **train_ds.repeat()** instead of *x=x_train, y=y_train*.

next issue I encountered is

```
100/741 [===>..........................] - ETA: 18:07 - loss: 3.7188 - accuracy: 0.04942020-06-23 14:52:29.232604: E tensorflow/core/lib/jpeg/jpeg_mem.cc:323] Premature end of JPEG data. Stopped at line 910/1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "product_detection.py", line 123, in <module>
    model.fit(train_ds.repeat(), epochs=15, batch_size= BATCH_SIZE, validation_data=valid_ds.repeat(), steps_per_epoch= TRAIN_STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_steps=VAL_STEPS_PER_EPOCH)
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 611, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2420, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1665, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1746, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 598, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\sl199\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Invalid JPEG data or crop window, data size 101360
         [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Invalid JPEG data or crop window, data size 101360
         [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
         [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_1113]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function

2020-06-23 14:52:29.411288: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/cache_dataset_ops.cc:794] The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached contents of the dataset will be discarded. This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.
```

at this point I am completely lost, I suspect the **prepare_for_training function** I copied is not suitable for my application but I don't understand enough to make changes. It explicitly said that it is for a data set of 1000+ images while I'm working with **90k training and 10k validation data sets**. I try to change the batch_size yet the issue persists.

I am using TensorFlow-gpu with GTX 1050 Ti. May I ask for a pointer on how to proceed with this? Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1:** Changed my batch_size to 10 and this error appeared

```
3537/9484 [==========>...................] - ETA: 12:31 - loss: 3.7519 - accuracy: 0.02602020-06-23 16:10:13.148245: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:109 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[943,943,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
2020-06-23 16:10:13.159005: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:109 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[678,678,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
 Resou3538/9484 [==========>...................] - ETA: 12:31 - loss: 3.7519 - accuracy: 0.0260rce exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[956,956,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[943,943,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
         [[{{node convert_image/Cast}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

         [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[943,943,3] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
         [[{{node convert_image/Cast}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Comment: is there any file getting corrupted?

Comment: nope, I dont think so. Although at closer inspection of the raw data files I noticed some .tmp file got mixed up in couple of folder. Will that be enough to cause the error?

Comment: No. As you're not getting all the files from the folder. You're checking the CSV and reading only the listed images. If those images are not corrupted, it should be fine. One more thing. Can you please try to reduce the batch size to 10 and let me know the update?

Comment: Please see my edit on the main post thanks

Comment: Hi! It seems like I only receive that error when my image size is 'big'. I am able to use a pretrained model with a image size of (64,64,3) and receive error if i try to use big architectures. Could it possible that my hardware is actually causing these? I have 4gb of GPU RAM and 8gb DDR4 RAM.

Comment: Yes, I suspected the same and that is why asked you to reduce batch size. You can keep image size big and reduce the batch size. Your GPU memory was not enough.

Comment: Hi! I figure out something. I shouldn't be using ds.cache() as im working with a large dataset and about the GPU running out of resource, I should restart the kernel (clear gpu cache) and start the training. I havent encountered any error now.

Answer (score 0):

According to this section of the output :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Invalid JPEG data or crop window, data size 101360
         [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Invalid JPEG data or crop window, data size 101360
         [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
         [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
```

It seems like if some of your data are corrupted, check your data and remove the corrupted entries, that is a common error that you can check [HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/issues/455) and [THERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7434)

Comment: I did a check on my file and RAM neither seem to have problem.

Comment: Hi! It seems like I only receive that error when my image size is 'big'. I am able to use a pretrained model with a image size of (64,64,3) and receive error if i try to use big architectures. Could it possible that my hardware is actually causing these? I have 4gb of GPU RAM and 8gb DDR4 RAM.

Comment: Maybe you can preprocess your images training